# C# problem with object array

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I am fairly new to arrays in C# and am used to storing a mass of data in a string and in INI files and then breaking it down into basic arrays using delimiters...so yeh, my knowledge is almost none existent.

My main form class begin this definition:

```
public CAirportData[] _AirportData; //size not known
```

This is the method I am using to create the array:

```
...string[] airports = possibleAirports.Split(','); //size is known
foreach (string airport in airports)
 {
   string[] rwys = inif.Read(airport, "rwys").Split(':'); //size is known (2)
   _AirportData = new CAirportData[] { new CAirportData() { icao=airport, depRwy=rwys[0], arrRwy=rwys[1] } };
 }
```

I know this just boils down to my limited knowledge of objects and arrays. But I can't seem to find anything on the internet that uses this sort of thing. I have tried to combine other peoples code with little success.

I need the _AirportData array to be available outside of the form hence public and declared outside of any methods. I supose the main problem is that I am overwriting array and foreach airport I am creating a new array hence loosing the previous. I had tried moving the ..= new CAirportData[] to all sorts of places but Visual Studio doesn't like it.

Below is the class definition for CAirportData:

```
public class CAirportData
{
    public string icao { get; set; }
    public string depRwy { get; set; }
    public string arrRwy { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string result = string.Format("ICAO: {0}, Dep: {1}, Arr: {2}", this.icao, this.depRwy, this.arrRwy);
        return result;
    }
}

public class CMRunways
{
    public string icao { get; set; }
    public string depRwy { get; set; }
    public string arrRwy { get; set; }
}
```

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Read the first part. You are declaring an array _AirportData and then each time create new array of one element. 
In your case you should use Generic contatiners like List<CAirportData> or so.

Comment: Read the second. Yes, you are right. Read about List (examples are there too) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is generic List. Change the definition to:

```
public List<CAirportData> _AirportData = new List<CAirportData>();
```

Then the code in the loop to:

```
_AirportData.Add(new CAirportData { icao=airport, depRwy=rwys[0], arrRwy=rwys[1] });
```

Comment: You could also declare the array outside of the loop, since you know the size you want it to be (`airports.length`)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - it works very well. Thank you very much!

Comment: Cheers Govix, note jswolf19 comment as well, it's directed for you. :)

Answer (score -1):

This is what I would do...Create a static class, with a static property (airports) and add a static constructor to load the airports from file at the begining.

```
 public static class Session
 {
     public static CAirportData[] _AirportData;

     static Session()
     {
         string airports = possibleAirports.Split(",");
         foreach (string airport in airports)
         {
             string[] rwys = inif.Read(airport, "rwys").Split(':'); //size is known (2)
             _AirportData = new CAirportData[] { new CAirportData() { icao=airport, depRwy=rwys[0], arrRwy=rwys[1] } };
         }
     }
 }
```

Now you can access the array anywhere in the project like

```
MessageBox.Show(Session.CAirportData[0].depRwy);
```

Comment: `_AirportData` still won't contain all the data the OP wants it to.